# [linux][ompl] add library path

Tags: c++, linux, g++, linux-mint

I have installed the library ompl from http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/
My OS is Linux Mint 17 Qiana

I tried to compile OptimalPlanning.cpp as follow : $ g++ OptimalPlanning.cpp

I also tried the following: $ g++ -Wall -W -Werror -I/anon/omplapp main.cpp -o main -L/anon/omplapp/ -lompl -lompl_app

This is the error:

```
OptimalPlanning.cpp:37:40: fatal error: ompl/base/SpaceInformation.h: No such file or directory
#include <ompl/base/SpaceInformation.h>
                                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

I'm thinking I may need to add the ompl library as a default library. So I tried a couple thing but I still have the same problem.

Things I tried :

1. export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/user/omplapp/build/Release/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
2. sudo pluma /etc/ld.so.conf.d/randomLibs.conf and add /user/omplapp/build/Release/lib
3. I also modified the file libc.conf which was already there (in the folder /etc/ld.so.conf.d) to contain the path of my library

Do any of you guys understand what I don't ?
I don't understand what path should be given and where.

Thanks, jb

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
#include <ompl/base/SpaceInformation.h>
```

expects there to be the following directory tree with `SpaceInformation.h` and other files, too.

```
/usr/include/ompl/base
```

Either `SpaceInformation.h` does not live there, or there is no such directory.